# Angular2 Vendor Import expose module error

Tags: angular, import

I am having an error while trying to run my Angular2 app.

```
ERROR in ./src/vendor.browser.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'expose' in '/Users/adrien/Dev/go/src/github.com/adrien3d/base-front/src'
BREAKING CHANGE: It's no longer allowed to omit the '-loader' suffix when using loaders.
                 You need to specify 'expose-loader' instead of 'expose',
                 see https://webpack.js.org/guides/migrating/#automatic-loader-module-name-extension-removed
 @ ./src/vendor.browser.ts 4:0-31
```

Here is the concerned file:
vendor.browser.ts:

```
// Vendors
require("expose?jQuery!jquery");

import 'metismenu';
import 'bootstrap';

// Angular 2
import '@angular/platform-browser';
import '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import '@angular/core';
import '@angular/common';
import '@angular/forms';
import '@angular/http';
import '@angular/router';

// RxJS
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap';
```

I don't clearly see the point of this error since I am not trying to use expose, any idea?

Comment: use `require("expose-loader?jQuery!jquery");` instead of `require("expose?jQuery!jquery");`

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much

Comment: np, added the web pack reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Vendors
require("expose-loader?jQuery!jquery");

import 'metismenu';
import 'bootstrap';

// Angular 2
import '@angular/platform-browser';
import '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import '@angular/core';
import '@angular/common';
import '@angular/forms';
import '@angular/http';
import '@angular/router';

// RxJS
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap';
```

Reference: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/expose-loader